# Angularjs controller embed in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

How about embedding angularjs controller in a function. So that we can initiate whenever we want.

```
 fucntion execute() {

 angular.controller('ProductsPageController', ['$scope', '$http',   'InitService', function ($scope, $http, InitService) {
 })

  }
```

I think this a noob angularjs question. Please let me know the best approach to initiate controller without other modules like ngrouter etc..

Comment: what's the purpose of doing this?

Comment: you probably want to have a look on requirejs...it will allow you to lazy load files and organize them into modules. And your controller will be within a function as you want))

Comment: @sdfacre beacause my views are inserted dynamically. So i need to execute after it loads.

Comment: @VaibhavChiruguri Why do you need to define controllers after the views are loaded? What do you mean exactly by loading views?

Comment: @miensol my controller views are dynamic. i.e., It appends to the body after certain event. Normally controller compiles the static html. Angularjs doesnt complie late or lazy html dom elements. Hope you got the point.

Comment: Could you have the controller and a basic template then use $compile on the loaded content? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: are you trying to manipulate the template DOM in that controller? if no, put ng-controller on the root element of the template should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add controller inside any function. you can use it onece you initialize it.
eg.

```
angular.controller('ProductsPageController', function  () {
// here you can wright your business logic
});
```

then initialize it in your app so
you can call your controller directly.